# Layout: Need a cell that can be bigger than other cell in the same row

Tags: html, css, angular

The best way to explain what I'm trying to do is with this image: 
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKKWm.png)
<\b>

What I'm currently getting is this: 
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zZqv.png)

It almost works to think of this as 7 rows of data with two columns.  The problem is that in row 1 cell 2, the control needs to be the same size as 5 rows, but currently its height is only 1 row. Its height should span from Field x all the way down to Label E.

Here is an example code of one of the rows, so you can see I'm just using two different div classes, one called "row-two", and another for columns, which in this case is "col-1-12".  "row-two" and "col-1-12" are re-used frequently.

```
<div class="row-two" >
      <label for="someLabel" class="col-1-12">TheLabel:</label>
      <div class="col-2-12 left-align-button">
          <p-dropdown [options]="optionNames" [(ngModel)]="selectedSomething" [filter]="true" filterBy="label" [style]="{width:'80%'}" (onChange) = "onSomeChange()"></p-dropdown>
      </div>
      <label for="somethingElse" class="col-1-12">AnotherLabel:</label>
      <div class="col-3-12">
          <select multiple="true" size="12" [(ngModel)]="selectedSomething" style="width: 100%;" (ngModelChange) = "getDatesFromServer()" >

          <option title="{{something.label}}" *ngFor="let something of somethings" value= {{something.value.id}}>
            {{something.label}}
          </option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: CSS Grid is going to save your day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Jensei: the answer is CSS Grid.  This example here is basically going to be my solution: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example20/